# Open XML: Word - Getting all Paragraphs marked as "Heading1" style

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Using Word I have created a Docx with the standard normal.dot as a test. Hello-world level complexity.

I wish to get `all the paragraphs` which are styled with the "`Heading1`" `style` in Word.

I can get all the paragraphs, but don't know how to filter down to Heading1.

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFileName, false))
{
    paragraphs = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                    .OfType<Paragraph>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    [Test]
    public void FindHeadingParagraphs()
    {

        var paragraphs = new List<Paragraph>();

        // Open the file read-only since we don't need to change it.
        using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFileName, false))
        {
            paragraphs = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                .OfType<Paragraph>()
                .Where(p => p.ParagraphProperties != null && 
                            p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId != null && 
                            p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val.Value.Contains("Heading1")).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get null exception, only added: p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId != null &&