# How to find the closest sub-paragraph where a table is, in a docx document?

Tags: c#, openxml

From a docx file, I would like to extract only the tables and their related heading. In other words, I am interested in the tables and the heading each table belongs to ("lies under").

I am using [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) library.

Here is my draft:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

...
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filewithpath, false))
{
    Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    List<Table> tables = GetTables(body);
    List<string> Paragraphs = new List<string>();

    foreach (Table table in tables)
    {
        Paragraphs.Add(table.???); //I have no idea what to write here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through siblings of `table` and look for "heading" style in paragraph style info.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941878/8206975) to get "heading" style.

A pseudo code would be like:

```
siblings = table.GetElementsBefore();  // You can get all the siblings before the table
siblings_rev = siblings.Reverse();     // reverse it to start from closest sibling
foreach(sibling in siblings_rev)
    if(sibling.style_properties.contains("header"))
        string title = sibling.value;
```